# Aggregate gate functions

Tags: function, aggregate

All the aggregate functions don't get highlighted in blue whenever I type them out, it's like they have been disabled or something. All the other keywords are working except the aggregate functions

They are supposed get highlighted in blue just like all the other keywords, I need help on how to solve this issue please.